# How to scroll individual page when we use tabbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to make `scrollable` page in `flutter` when we use `Tabbar` in flutter.
I tried this code but this is not working.
In this code my whole `listview` I cannot see. How to display whole `listview` items while using `tabbar`.

So, how can I solve this problem.

```
Widget _listofitem() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: categoryDetail.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 100.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.cyanAccent),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    // child: NetworkImage(categoryDetail[index]),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Text(categoryDetail[index]['category_name'].toString()),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text(
            'Invitation Card Application',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          centerTitle: true,
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: myTabs,
            controller: _tabController,
          )
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
            return Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _listofitem(),
                  // _ofitem()
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(), 
        ));
  }
```

I want to change page on individual tab click and also do scroll in that individual page. So I display whole my page. What is the solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ListView.builder() widget you have set the property,

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

This is preventing the scroll on the list view. If you want to wrap the list view inside the container with the above properties, then wrap the container in the SingleChildScrollView widget.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(), 
);
```

By this, you can have the scroll effect and you will be able to see all the list view items